# How to make a round icon for shortcut

Tags: android, android-static-shortcuts, android-dynamic-shortcuts

I'm trying to add Android shortcuts into the application, including dynamic shortcuts and icons for them will be created from bitmaps. Right now it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the dynamic shortcut icons have a square image in center, but I need it to take all space of an icon, so there would be no white background.
The code:

```
Bitmap interlocutorAvatar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_conference);
ShortcutInfo shortcutInfo = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, peer.getId())
                        .setLongLabel("Dynamic shortcut")
                        .setShortLabel("Dynamic")
                        .setIcon(Icon.createWithBitmap(interlocutorAvatar))
                        .setIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setClass(context, VCEngine.appInfo().getActivity(ActivitySwitcher.ActivityType.CHAT))
                                .putExtra(CustomIntent.EXTRA_PEER_ID, peer.getId())
                                .putExtra(CustomIntent.EXTRA_CHAT_ID, peer.getId()))
                        .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found one possible solution, and that is to use adaptive icons. It looks a little bit weird to me, but hey as long as it works.
I've used AdaptiveIconDrawable and here is how to do it:

1. We need to convert our Bitmap for shortcut icon to BitmapDrawable.
2. We create a AdaptiveIconDrawable and pass BitmapDrawable to it.
3. Then we create another bitmap and draw our AdaptiveIconDrawable on it's canvas, thus converting AdaptiveIconDrawable back into Bitmap (Adaptive Bitmap I guess?)
4. And finally we use **Icon.createWithAdaptiveBitmap** method to set short cut Icon

The code to convert bitmap to Adaptive Bitmap:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    public static Bitmap convertBitmapToAdaptive(Bitmap bitmap, Context context) {
        Drawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
        AdaptiveIconDrawable drawableIcon = new AdaptiveIconDrawable(bitmapDrawable, bitmapDrawable);
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawableIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawableIcon.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
        drawableIcon.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawableIcon.draw(canvas);
        return result;
    }
```

Then you could set the Icon of your shortcut like this :

```
setIcon(Icon.createWithAdaptiveBitmap(convertBitmapToAdaptive(yourBitmap, context)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to the imageView that are loading the images in your xml file

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: You can use Picasso Library for imaging handle https://github.com/square/picasso